# ANT JWSC fails in JDK 8 with com/sun/mirror/apt/annotationprocessorfactory

Tags: java, web-services, ant, java-8, wsgen

We are using ant jwsc to generate  webservice. Everything working fine in JDK 7, While migrating to JDK 8 (jdk8 u 131) we get the below error and webservice build fails. any workaround for this ?

Quick google search returning annotationprocessorfactory is removed from jdk8

```
weblogic.wsee.tools.WsBuildException: Error processing JAX-WS web services
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.jws.jaxws.JAXWSProcessor.finish(JAXWSProcessor.java:238)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.jws.process.CompositeProcessor.finish(CompositeProcessor.java:58)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.jws.build.JwsCompiler.buildWebServices(JwsCompiler.java:544)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.jws.build.JwsCompiler.compile(JwsCompiler.java:493)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwsModule.generate(JwsModule.java:379)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwsModule.build(JwsModule.java:256)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwscTask.execute(JwscTask.java:184)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:758)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mirror/apt/AnnotationProcessorFactory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.defineClassFromData(AntClassLoader.java:1146)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.getClassFromStream(AntClassLoader.java:1324)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1341)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1088)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.jws.jaxws.JAXWSProcessor.runApt(JAXWSProcessor.java:390)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.jws.jaxws.JAXWSProcessor.finish(JAXWSProcessor.java:143)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessorFactory
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1400)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1341)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1088)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: The official API is at [`javax.annotation.processing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?javax/annotation/processing/package-summary.html), since Java 6…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading the JAXB jars the issue is resolved. Build is Success.

Comment: which JAXB jars version you where using, and to which version did you upgrade?